# Quantity string resources in Android: Differences between English and Russian

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

**When I use quantity string resources in Android, it's easy for English and works as expected:**

```
String output = getResources().getQuantityString(R.plurals.my_resource, i, i);
```

For `1`, this returns the string defined in the quantity `one`, for `2` to `70`, it returns the quantity string `other`, for example.

**But when I use the same code with Russian `Locale` set, the output is different:**

It uses the quantity string `one` not only for input `1`, but also for inputs `21`, `31`, `41`, `51` - for all numbers that end with "1". Why? Is that intended (even correct) behaviour? I can just say that, to me, this looks very strange. Well, when I let google translate the strings `30 dogs`, `31 dogs` and `32 dogs` - the output for the noun is always the same.

I've seen similar behaviour for Lithuanian language, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that intended (even correct) behaviour?

I don't speak Russian, but a quick search suggests [this is correct](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Russian/Grammar/Genitive_case#Counting):

> ### Counting
>
> When denoting how many of something you have, we usually place the
>   object in question in the genitive case. However, Russian has some key
>   differences to English:
>
> - If there is 1, 21, 31, 41, etc, of something, they go in the nominative singular.
> - If there is 2, 3, 4, 22, 23, 24, 32, 33, 34, etc, of something, use the genitive singular.
> - If there is 5 to 19, 25 to 29, 35 to 39, etc, or something, use the genitive plural.

Answer (score 4):

Behavior is correct.

In russian there are multiple forms of the same word when you count:

"дерево" is a "tree" in english. But the word changes its postfix depends of count

```
    1 деревО
    2 деревА
    3 деревА
    4 деревА
    5 деревЬЕВ
    6 деревЬЕВ
    7 деревЬЕВ
    ...
    21 дерево
    22 деревА
    23 деревА
    24 деревА
    25 деревЬЕВ
    26 деревЬЕВ
    ...
    31 дерево
    32 деревА
    33 деревА
    34 деревА
    35 деревЬЕВ
    36 деревЬЕВ

and so on
```

Excludes are 11, 12, 13, 14.

I'm not sure if next example is good, but you can take it like not "one", but "first". for example in English we say 21 - "twenty first", but not "twenty ones", "twenty second", but not "twenty twos". Excludes are 11, 12, 13, 14 (we don't say "ten first", or "tenfirstteen" or something. just eleven)

http://www.russianlessons.net/lessons/lesson11_main.php